# How to keep just the intersection of two dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, date, pandas

I have a dataset with dates in index 11000 dates. I have a second dataset with just one column made of dates.

I just want to keep the row of the first dataset with the dates included in the second dataset.

```
ex.
[In] DataSet1
[Out] 
                     1           2           3           4           5 
 2019-04-19         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN   
 2019-04-20         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN   
 2019-04-21         apple       NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN   
 2019-04-22         NaN         NaN         peer        NaN         NaN   
 2019-04-23         NaN         car         NaN         NaN         NaN   
 2019-04-24         NaN         NaN         NaN         yellow      NaN   
 2019-04-25         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN 

[In] DataSet2 
[Out] 
0  2019-04-21
1  2019-04-23
```

What I want

```
[In] "Intersection" (which is not really an intersection) btween the 2 datasets. 
[Out]
                    1           2           3           4           5   
 2019-04-21         apple       NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN     
 2019-04-23         NaN         car         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

again, the second dataset just contain some dates.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Try this: `DataSet1.loc[DataSet2]` (if `DataSet2` is a Series) or `DataSet1.loc[DataSet2['column_name']]` if `DataSet2` is a DataFrame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first check if both `dtype` are same and then select by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) as pointed [MaxU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43307158/how-to-keep-just-the-intersection-of-two-dataframe/43307902#comment73680037_43307158) in comment:

```
print (DataSet1.index.dtype)
datetime64[ns]

print (DataSet2['col'].dtype)
datetime64[ns]

print (DataSet2.columns)
Index(['col'], dtype='object')


print (DataSet2)
         col
0 2019-04-21
1 2019-04-23

df = DataSet1.loc[DataSet2['col']]
print (df)
                1    2    3    4   5
2019-04-21  apple  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
2019-04-23    NaN  car  NaN  NaN NaN
```

Another solution with [`intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html):

```
idx = DataSet1.index.intersection(DataSet2['col'])
print (idx)
DatetimeIndex(['2019-04-21', '2019-04-23'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

df = DataSet1.loc[idx]
print (df)
                1    2    3    4   5
2019-04-21  apple  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
2019-04-23    NaN  car  NaN  NaN NaN
```